# Citrix Receiver Launcher alert unable to locate using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, citrix

I am unable to locate Citrix Receiver Launcher alert using Selenium with Python where it throws NoAlertPresentException. I am accessing the Citrix StoreFront using webapp URL and facing issue in automating the scenario where need to accept the alert.
Attached the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KflVN.png)

I have tried various solutions including keyboard mouse actions, explicit wait with expected conditions, alert.accept() but none are useful on it.
Can someone please help out here? I have seen few other old posts but none could provide solution

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED!!!!**
Added below chrome options in my config.yml file of project from where we pick chrome preferences:
'user-data-dir=C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User
Data', 'profile-directory=Default'

This is picking my system's chrome browser's profile in which I have saved setting of allowing web app to open the application via my citrix receiver alert as you can see in my attached image above. Now, I no longer see this alert while test execution in selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Locally SOLVED, but not working in Remote VM.

Solved locally Without touching profile, with the below, in .Net + Selenium

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
(Note: in Remote VM, while not login, and if the script is running, then, getting "Access Denied" error)